# PostgreSQL : How to select rows from multiple tables inside different schemas?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select all rows from multiple tables inside various schemas.

These are the tables inside different schemas

```
schema_1-->ABC_table_1,XYZ_table_2
schema_2-->ABC_table_1,JLK_table_2
.
.
schema_N-->ABC_table_1,LMN_table_2
```

I am trying to select all rows from `table_2` from all schemas:

This query is giving me all the tables:

```
SELECT
    table_schema || '.' || table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND
    table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

What i need to do is something like

```
select * from schema_1.XYZ_table_2
Union all
select * from schema_2.JLK_table_2
.
.
schema_2.LMN_table_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if this option can work for you :

```
select row_to_json(row) from (select * from table1 ) row
UNION ALL
select row_to_json(row) from (select * from table2 ) row
;
```

If you dont want to work with JSON/HStore datamanipulation you can also try to make dynamic sql select creation for all possible columns in the schema then UNION ALL can still work .
Json looks pretty easier to do this task and also very supported to do any further actions.